# fast way to stack vectors into a matrix in Python

Tags: python, loops, numpy, matrix, vector

I want to stack 100k vector of the same lentgh (500) into a single matrix in python but it takes too much time.

here is my code:

```
stacked = all_vectors[0]
for i in range(1,100000):
    stacked = np.column_stack((stacked ,all_vectors[i]))
```

Do you know how to make this quicker?

Comment: Any reason `np.column_stack(all_vectors)` doesn't work?

Comment: yes but the all_vectors actually contains 500k vectors and I only want a subset of those

Comment: Can't you select the subset of vectors first, e.g. `all_vectors[n:m]`?  Columnstack makes a new array each time, so should not be use iteratively.  List indexing and append is faster.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should get the answer you want with

```
stacked = np.column_stack(all_vectors[:100000])
```

There appears to be no difference between that and

```
stacked = np.array(all_vectors[:100000]).transpose()
```

as you can see from this interactive session:

```
>>> stacked = np.column_stack(all_vectors[:100000])
>>> sstacked = np.array(all_vectors[:100000]).transpose()
>>> stacked == sstacked
array([[ True,  True,  True, ...,  True,  True,  True],
       [ True,  True,  True, ...,  True,  True,  True],
       [ True,  True,  True, ...,  True,  True,  True],
       ...,
       [ True,  True,  True, ...,  True,  True,  True],
       [ True,  True,  True, ...,  True,  True,  True],
       [ True,  True,  True, ...,  True,  True,  True]], dtype=bool)
>>> (stacked == sstacked).all()
True
```

*EDIT*: Timing results appear to prefer the second method:

```
%%timeit
vector = list(range(1, 1+10))
all_vectors = [vector] *100_000
result = np.column_stack(all_vectors)

396 ms ± 18.4 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

%%timeit
vector = list(range(1, 1+10))
all_vectors = [vector] *100_000
result = np.array(all_vectors)
np.array(all_vectors[:100000]).transpose()

152 ms ± 3.16 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Comment: `column_stack` turns all inputs into 2d arrays, and then does an `axis=1` concatenate.

Comment: Thanks. I added timings to show that array creation followed by transposition is quicker.